# Change of TextInput value on Admin-on-Rest before validation?

Tags: admin-on-rest

On `admin-on-rest`, how can we use the onChange handler to change the value of a TextInput while typing (i.e. before validation)?

See example:

```
const handleChange = (e, newValue) => {
    const value = newValue.toUpperCase();
    // ???? How do we inform the TextInput of the new value, since we do not have a state inside this component but only in REDUX? 
};
```

...

```
 <Edit title={<TitleEdit />} {...props}>
    <SimpleForm validate={validateCreateEdit}>
        <TextInput label="BRAND" source="brand" onChange={handleChange.bind(this)} />
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onChange to update the state of the parent component. There you can reformat the value to uppercase.

You can then use the material UI value prop to display the typed value in state.

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field

EDIT: The assumption in the above is that you will be creating a stateful component to store and format the correct value. Since one usually does not want to submit the form till the user has filled out all the fields, dispatching a submit action will be overkill. Essentially reformat the value locally till the user is ready to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks Kunal, can you please demonstrate what you mean by "update the state of the parent component"? You mean to dispatch an action? It is not very clear to me how it is done so that SimpleForm gets this value from REDUX state, can you please elaborate on this?
Thanks again!